# Compiler not working as intended or me not being able to find the flaw in my logic in C++ program

Tags: c++, arrays, object, output, operator-overloading

The following is supposed to return me with matrix who is the sum of m1 and m2 matrix provided prior in the program however, it returns with the garbage values instead.

The problem am trying to solve with this is as follows:

> Write a program for developing a matrix class which can handle integer matrices of different dimensions. Also overload the operator for addition, multiplication & comparison of matrices.

I have read the code multiple times and can't put my finger on the mistake, any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
    int rows, cols;
    int * arr;
    public:
        Matrix(int rows, int cols) : rows(rows), cols(cols) 
        {
            arr = new int[rows * cols];
        }

        void insert()
        {
            cout << "Enter the values of matrix from position [00] to ["<< rows << cols <<"], seprated with space : " << endl;
            for(int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
                cin >> arr[i];
        }

        void retrieve()
        {
            cout << "The Matrix stored is : " << endl;
            for(int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
            {
                cout << " " << arr[i] << " ";
                if((i + 1) % cols == 0) cout << endl;
            }
        }

        bool operator==(Matrix other)
        {
            if(rows != other.rows || cols != other.cols)
                return false;

            for(int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
            {
                if(arr[i] != other.arr[i])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        Matrix operator+(Matrix other)
        {
            if(rows != other.rows || cols != other.cols)
            {
                cout << "Number of Row(s)/Column(s) unequal!" << endl <<"Addition not Possible.";
                return Matrix(0,0);
            }
            else
            {
                Matrix sum(rows, cols);
                for(int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
                    sum.arr[i] =  arr[i] + other.arr[i];

                return sum;
            }
        }

        ~Matrix()
        {
            delete [] arr;
        }
};

Matrix matrix_creator()
{
    int rows, columns;

    cout << "Enter the number of Rows and Columns in the matrix, respectively : " << endl;
    cin >> rows >> columns;

    Matrix m(rows, columns);
    m.insert();
    m.retrieve();

    return m;
}

int main()
{
    Matrix m1 = matrix_creator();
    Matrix m2 = matrix_creator();

    cout << "Matrix Addition Result:" << endl;
    (m1 + m2).retrieve();

    if (m1 == m2) {
        cout << "Matrices are equal." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Matrices are not equal." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Here is the outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0knvm.png)
And you can see how either of those are not expected, kindly help.

Comment: `bool operator==(Matrix other)` -- Your `Matrix` class is not safely copyable or assignable, as it violates the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).  You are passing `Matrix` by value, and that invokes the copy constructor.  See the **Managing resources** section of the link I posted to see why your class fails.

Comment: Also, at the very least, you should use `std::vector<int> arr;` and not `int *arr`.  Don't be surprised if magically, all or most of your issues go away.

Comment: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) might help

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger to see why the code outputs the unexpected results?

Comment: `Matrix operator+(Matrix other)` -- This also will run into issues since you are passing by value.  Just to show you how bad it can get, this simple two line program shows problems: `int main() { Matrix m = matrix_creator(); Matrix m2 = m; }` -- That simple two line program ends up with a double-delete error.

Comment: Looking at the code, the solution is to simply use `std::vector<int> arr;`, initialize `arr` in the constructor to `arr( rows * cols )`, and get rid of the `Matrix` destructor.   In addition, passing `Matrix` by (const) reference instead of by-value should be done.  Are you allowed to use `std::vector`?

Comment: Who taught you to use `arr = new int[rows * cols];` instead of `std::vector<int> arr(rows*cols);` ?  Because whoever taught you that is not teaching you current C++

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Am not allowed to use STL libraries such as vector, that's the point, or else the question be pointless.

Comment: @ARSHPATHAK *Am not allowed to use STL libraries such as vector, that's the point, or else the question be pointless.* -- First, you mentioned nothing about not being able to use `std::vector`.  Second, the issue is at the duplicate link about the rule of 3.  Third, `std::vector` has been officially part of standard C++ for **26 years** now.  At some point it really gets ridiculous to **not** use it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Am sorry for not mentioning it, I thought giving the whole code would imply that I am looking for the solution with my current code and not with inclusion of some other library like vector or map, I know using it would make this easy but the challenge is to not use it.

Comment: Well, you have to implement a user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator if you can't use `std::vector`.  But if you were not told this before you got this assignment, then the course you are taking is severly lacking in giving you the right information.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I agree whole heartedly, half of the stuff I learnt is from youtube by myself as the university course is exactly what you said. Inefficient.

Comment: @ARSHPATHAK Knowing the rule of three is what separates the beginners from those programmers who at least partly know what they are doing. So congratulations, you learned something important today.

Comment: @ARSHPATHAK Given your requirements the correct way to answer this is to write your own implementation of `std::vector` first (greatly simplified of course) and then use that implementation in your matrix class. That approach really shows up the stupidity of the 'can't use std::vector' rule.

Comment: @john yeah, first time hearing about it but I guess I did learn something new today, find the solution which works for me though.

Comment: Matrix(const Matrix &other) : rows(other.rows), cols(other.cols), arr(new int[rows * cols]){
            for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
                arr[i] = other.arr[i];
        }
        Matrix& operator=(Matrix &other) 
        {
            if (this != &other) 
            { 
                delete [] arr;
                rows = other.rows;
                cols = other.cols;
                arr = new int[rows * cols];
                for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++) 
                    arr[i] = other.arr[i];
            }
            return *this;
        }

Comment: @ARSHPATHAK Ok, but you should post updates in the original question, not as a comment.  The second thing is that the assignment operator you have has an issue, and that is you `delete []` the array before calling `new []`.  What if `new[]` throws an exception?  You changed the values of `row` and `column` prematurely, and your original data from the array is now gone, thus a corrupted object.  Instead see the [copy/swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom).  Go to the **failed solution** section of that link.  It looks like your code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I see, I will the successful approach mentioned there then.